# Updating an object inside of an array MongoDB Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I am trying to update an object inside of an array. Here is my structure:

```js
"_id": "ubtQP9EjmxhXS5z98",
  "name": "My Data",
  "desc": "What songs should I play at my wedding?",
  "private": false,
  "suggestions": [
    {
      "name": "Vote 1",
      "link": "http://www.website.com/",
      "votes": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Vote 2",
      "votes": 0
    }
  ],
  "author": "tovd9Win3C3fntgyR",
  "createdAt": "2016-01-10T08:36:37.014Z"
```

I want to update the votes on the first object in "suggestions" by 1. At the moment I have the following code but it does NOT work.

```js
Polls.update("ubtQP9EjmxhXS5z98", {
    $inc: {suggestions.$.votes: 1},
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the array index of the embedded document, you can specify the document using the embedded document’s position using the [dot notation.](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-dot-notation)

You don't need the positional [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#definition) update operator here because you know the position of the element you want to update.

> The positional `$` operator identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array.

Also to use the `$` operator the array field must appear as part of the query document.

```
Polls.update({"_id": "ubtQP9EjmxhXS5z98"}, {
    "$inc": {"suggestions.1.votes": 1},
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query, in the "find" part, you have to specify what you are looking in your array. Per example: `"suggestions.name" = "Vote1"`